# To give a lift - collocation or idiom?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

'To give a lift'
Is it a collocation or an idiom?
How can we call it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, after reading different sources in Google I'm not sure whether you can call it a 100% an idiom or a 100% a collocation.

If we look at the definition of the word "**idiom**" we can't regard the phrase "**give a lift**" as an idiom. Unfortunately, since from the definition of the word "**collocation**" the two words "**give**" and "**a lift**" do indeed form a collocation.

In most dictionaries collocations of the word "**lift**" list "**give a lift**" and some even list it as "**give somebody a lift**" with either the usage of "**transport via vehicle**" or "**cheer up**" as well as the standard meanibg if "**raise into the air**".

However, some sources and idiom lists as well as web sites, list it as an idiom.

I was trying to search for information regarding a phrase being an idiom and a collocation at the same time, but looks like such a thing does not exist. However, some sources indicate that an idiom can become a collocation over time.

Comment: But now that noun **lift** has among its established meanings "transport somewhere", the phrase "give you a lift" would be a collocation, since the meaning of the phrase is discernible by consulting the meaning of the individual words, not opaque, as is the case with an idiom, such as "He's just pulling your leg."

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo So it's both an idiom and a collocation?

Comment: If we accept as the definition of **idiom** that it is a phrase whose meaning cannot be derived from the meaning of its words, then "give you a lift" is not an idiom. *He needed a lift to the station.*  We can use **lift** like a normal noun in other constructions.  "Pulling your leg" is an idiom.  You can know what "pull" means and know what "leg" means and you will be no closer to the meaning of the phrase.

Comment: And **lift** was always semantically related to **carry**, whereas **leg** has nothing to do with teasing or joking.